# Extract a value from an intermediate table, in a has_many througth relationship rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing a project and I'm going through the permissions, my database model is more or less like this: I have a has_many through relationship, between user (done with Devise) and groups (made with scaffold name description: text), through the membership table, and the groups with activities (another basic scaffold), through permissions, which has:

1) activity_id: references

2) group_id: references

3) c: boolean (to create, if c = true, the group the user is in can create activities)

4) r: boolean (for reading, if r = true, the group the user is in can see activities)

5) u: boolean (for update, if u = true, the group in which the user is can edit activities)

6) d: boolean (to destroy, if d = true, the group the user is in can delete activities)

7) o: boolean (for own, if o = true, the group the user is in can only manage the activities that he has created)

I need:

1) That there is some parameter so that one group can make users crud in another group, that is, administer it.

2) From the form, when creating a group, you can manage the permissions of `c, r, u, d, o` on the different activities that may exist.

3) That the user can only manage the things he has created depending on whether `o` not it is true or false.

Comment: What is `group_ids`?. You didn't mention a Group model. Why `c, r, u, d, o` are on the Membership model? This is what your post says. Maybe they are in the User model

Comment: Sorry, activity_ids. And I need put `c, r, u, d, o` in memberships, because I want many users to be in many activities, if I put them in user or activities, the relationship would logically be one to one

Comment: If the user can create activities, the `c` is a an attribute of the user, not the Membership. The Membership only needs to have the user_id and activity_id.

Comment: No, because I want each activity, the user has different `c, r, u, d, o` permits

Comment: When the user has no activities: can he create an Activity? Where is the `c` privilege in this first case?.  If the user can create an activity (he has c==true in a membership), when he creates a new activity and a new Membership, will this membership have also the 'c'? and the other privileges?. I don't think you are right, but maybe your use case is unusual.

Comment: Yes, my case is unusual because the project have other modules, but the problem is that, I need send a value from the form to the controller, for save that params. How I can send a true/false to `c, r, u, d, o`?

Comment: And how I can make the `o` (the user can only manage the things that he has created)

Comment: You mentioned Projects and Modules for the first time in your comment. I think there are many things we don't know about your use case so that we cannot help. With the information I have I believe your models are not a good design.

Comment: Because those modules are for the future, the project is still young, I'm just starting it, well thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok, I developed my idea of the project better, with that information, do you think you can help me?

Answer (score 0):

**I think your models should be like this.**

```
class User << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :owned_groups, class_name: "Group" #The groups he has created
  has_many :memberships                       #Association to groups he has joined
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships     #The groups he has joined
end

class Group << ApplicationRecord
  belong_to :owner, class_name: "User" #The user who created the group. He sets premissions.
  has_many :group_activities                       #Association to activities
  has_many :activities, through: :group_activities #The group activities
end

class Activity << ApplicationRecord
  has_many :group_activities                    #Association to groups
  has_many :groups, through: :group_activities  #The groups where this activity belongs
end

class GroupActivity << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group                     
  belongs_to :activity                 
end

class Membership << ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user                     #This user is member of...
  belongs_to :group                    #this group.

  # This table should have the 
  # permissions for this user 
  # in this group (create activities, etc.). 
  # The Owner of the group can define these permissions
end
```

I can continue improving the answer if you think this models are correct.

Comment: Much user can be into groups, much groups has much users, through memberships, and much groups can has much activities, much activities has much groups through permissions, and permissions contain `c, r, u, d, o`

Comment: I changed the model so that many groups can have many activities (an now I see GroupActivity is what you called Permission)

Comment: But I think permissions must be handled in the Membership model (if the user can create, edit, update o delete activities in this group, so it depends on the group and the user). Privileges to handle activities should not be associated to a particular activity (unless you want to define permissions individually for each activity, but I don't think so).

Comment: We can not place the crud permissions on the user, because then we would have to assign those permissions on each user, so create the group model. I want to create a group you can assign the permissions you have within each activity created in the system, and that when creating an activity the same thing happens, that you can assign the permissions of each group in that particular activity.

Comment: sorry, in my house there was a power failure and then the internet fell

Comment: haha. Sorry for what? I thought you continued working on these models...

Comment: No, what you have I think is fine, although I do not know what this is for: belong_to: owner, class_name: "User". But I guess you know what you're doing, I just feel a little bit based on what I have in my head :) Please continue

Comment: It’s the owner of the group. The one that creates the group and can invite members. It’s the one that sets permissions for other members of this group. I don’t know if you need it.

Comment: No, the group is the one that receives the permits, in such a way that when you edit the permissions of a group, also those of all the users that are in it

Comment: So all users have the same permissions on a group? (if they are members of this group). And who sets the permission for a group?

Comment: An user with permissions for the that activity (make groups is a activity)

Comment: I'm still confused. I though anyone could create a group (and be its owner) and then he could set permissions for the group an all its members. If creating a group needs a permission: where is this permission set? How will the first group be created?

Comment: With a seed, the seed will make the first user, admin group, and some activities that I can think of after

Answer (score -1):

To answer your first question - I hope your model may looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :activities, through: :memberships

  delegate :c, to: :memberships #this way you can access c value with user 

end
```

so

```
user = User.find_by (id: 1)
user.c # will return the value true/false
```

To answer your second question - I need a bit clarification on this line

> I also need to know how to create this relationship from the form

Relationship between which models??

Comment: I need send a value from the form to the controller, for save that params. How I can send a true/false to c,r,u,d,o?

Comment: It doesn't make sense a down vote without proper reason for that

Comment: I did not do it, I just have 3 point of reputation, it does not let me vote, I do not know who did it

Comment: @DanielOrtin Hey thanks for your reply. I didn't mean it was you. I posted here because if any other user see this, at least they'll put a comment before down vote.

Comment: No, I was editing the question, look again please :)